# facebook user id

Tags: php, facebook, sdk

I want to use Facebook ID to welcome all facebook user that enter my page. Example:

> Hello *** name ***, Welcome to my page!

I try to use it with PHP SDK and copy SDK files to my hosting. That's the code that I tried to use :

```
<?php
require_once 'facebook.php';
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId' =>'1234',
    'secret' => '12345',
    'cookie' => true,
    'domain' => 'http://www.facebook.com/Guides4All.Co.IL/'
));

$session = $facebook->getSession();
if (!$session) {
    //user not logged into facebook
    $uName = "Guess";
} else {
    try {
        $user_id = $facebook->getUser();
        $tt = "/" . $user_id;
        $me = $facebook->api($tt);
        $uName = $me["name"];
    }
    catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    }
}
echo "Welcome $uName";
?>
```

Nut I got an error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method Facebook::getSession() in /*****.php on line 11
```

What can I do to fix this? What is `getSession()` and what to do now?

Comment: `domain` option you using isn't really domain but URL. BTW, In fact there is no such config option for PHP-SDK...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, basically, it's because the `Facebook::getSession()` method doesn't exist.
In other words `$session = $facebook->getSession();` just won't work.

The session is already initiated when you instantiate the Facebook object.

The code should be more like the example found at the [SDK located at GitHub](https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk/blob/master/examples/example.php)

Comment: Thank you for your answers. 
So i tried to change `$session = $facebook->getSession();` to `$user = $facebook->getUser();`
now the page Working, but not giving me the facebook userName. thats say me "welcome Guess"
and i want to get : Welcome **name** !
so what to do to fix this? 

Thanks!!

Comment: I wouldn't know, since the code you provided in the question wouldn't work. You should try implementing the example I linked to, so you can see what variables you have available and how to use them (including the name).

Comment: did you saw this tricks in another pages ?
like another pages that welcomes there users

Comment: I use it myself on one of my websites. Why?

Comment: with FBML or PHP SDK?
As i know, to use it by phpSDK it must that the facebook user that enter my page will confirm the app. thats true?

Comment: Well, I use a combination of both; the FBML to get website plugins and the PHP SDK to gain tracking of the user and link them to their events, uploads, forum posts, etc. But yes, they need to approve my site as an application.

Answer (score 1):

There is no method `getSession` in new PHP-SDK. You should use `getUser` method to get user id.

To get this working you should [authenticate user](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication) first. You can use [`getLoginUrl`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/facebook-getLoginUrl/) method to create URL that user need visit to connect with your application.

You need to read documentation for [Authentication](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication), [PHP-SDK](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php) and dig in [examples](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk/tree/master/examples).

Comment: Thank you for your answers. 
So i tried to change `$session = $facebook->getSession();` to `$user = $facebook->getUser();`
now the page Working, but not giving me the facebook userName. thats say me "welcome Guess"
and i want to get : Welcome **name** !
so what to do to fix this? 

Thanks!!

Comment: just get the user id than do a call to graph.facebook.com and it will return the name as JSON

Answer (score 1):

This will give you the visiting users full name.  It works even though it's been deprecated.

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#appId=YOUR_APP_ID&xfbml=1"></script>
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
        appId: 'YOUR_APP_ID',
        cookie: true,
        xfbml: true,
        oauth: true
  });
  (function() {
        var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;
        e.src = document.location.protocol +
            '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
        document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
  }());
</script>
<fb:serverFbml><script type="text/fbml"><fb:userlink uid="loggedinuser"/></script></fb:serverFbml>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$facebook = new Facebook(…);
$user = $facebook->getUser();
if ($user) {
  try {
    // Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated.
    $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    error_log($e);
    $user = null;
  }
}
```

//$user_profile get all information about that user. Then print what you want in that array.